# Javascript: Problema de uso de array vindo do php

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo uma iteração com php e javascript e estou com um problema. o Javascript aciona o arquivo php e recebe o array do php via json_encode. Depois disso, eu consigo ler o array no Javascript, mas não consigo usa-lo para outros tratamentos. Seguem os códigos:

```
var retorno;
var requisicao = new XMLHttpRequest();
requisicao.onload = reqListener;
requisicao.open("get", "../scr/farol_laudos_action.php", true);
requisicao.send(); 

function reqListener() {
    var dados = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    retorno = dados;
};

alert(retorno[0]);
```

Dessa forma que está, retorna a página em branco. O que estou fazendo de errado?
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente está tudo certo com seu código, o que posso notar será apenas um parâmetro que você deve passa diferente, segue o trecho de código.

```
requisicao.open("get", "../scr/farol_laudos_action.php", true);
```

Esse último parâmetro, caso seja `TRUE`, a sua consulta irá trabalhar de modo assíncrona, ou seja, não irá esperar o retorno para atribuir a variável, no seu caso você quer atribuir à variável e utilizar esse resultado, então deve alterar o parâmetro para `FALSE`, tornando a função síncrona, ficando dessa forma.

```
requisicao.open("get", "../scr/farol_laudos_action.php", false);
```

Referência : [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou certinho!

Answer (score 2):

Você está trabalhando com funções assíncronas, por conta disso você deve fazer todo o tratamento da função usando `promise` ou `async` `await`. O `alert(retorno[0])` não vai funcionar pois é uma variável síncrona, não um estado assíncrono, por exemplo.

Você deverá estudar um pouco de Javascript assíncrono, pois é um assunto um pouco mais complexo e não há uma forma rápida de lidar com ele sem saber um pouco sobre. Segue alguns ótimos artigos pra aprender sobre:

[JavaScript assíncrono: callbacks, promises e async functions](https://medium.com/@alcidesqueiroz/javascript-ass%C3%ADncrono-callbacks-promises-e-async-functions-9191b8272298)

[Entendendo o async e o await em JavaScript](https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-o-async-e-o-await-em-javascript/)

[Entendendo Promises de uma vez por todas](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/entendendo-promises-de-uma-vez-por-todas-32442ec725c2)

P.S.: O ajax (o XMLHttpRequest que você ta usando) trabalha de forma assíncrona.

Comment: Na própria consulta é possível definir se quer usar ela de modo assíncrono ou síncrono.
`httpRequest.open('GET', 'url', true);`
Nesse último parâmetro define se a função é assíncrono ou síncrono.

Comment: Eric Santana, obrigado pela explicação! Para o momento, troquei o parâmetro para false para que funcione de forma síncrona como foi mencionado, mas estudarei a forma assíncrona. Obrigado!